# Delete multiple attributes based on condition in one script

Tags: xquery, basex

I have 20-24 xml files where I want to remove whole lines if they contain certain attribute-values, they are all more or less nested like that (1 element and plenty attribute/value pairs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RT_VAL_ACC STATUS="0" ADDITIVE="" SRC_PID="" REASON="" F001="V6050" ACCID1="00000000DUMMYGMP_001DUMDER_001L" VALID1="11" ACC206="0"/>
<RT_VAL_ACC STATUS="0" ADDITIVE="" SRC_PID="" REASON="" F001="V6050" ACCID1="00000000DUMMYGMP_001DUMDER_001L" VALID1="12" ACC206="-1"/>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document date="2019-01-31" level="V6050" name="mpeMasterTablesExport">
<RT_REL_ENT_ACC STATUS="0" ADDITIVE="" SRC_PID="" REASON="" F001="V6050" ENTID1="00000000DUMMYGMP_001" ACCID1="00000000DUMMYGMP_001DUMDER_001L" RELID1="10"/>
<RT_REL_ENT_ACC STATUS="0" ADDITIVE="" SRC_PID="" REASON="" F001="V6050" ENTID1="00000000DUMMYGMP_001" ACCID1="0000000000000000000DUMMYGMP_KTO_045" RELID1="14"/>
```

I've put all of them in a baseX Database to manipulate them and by themselves the below queries work perfectly fine:

```
for $x in //RT_VAL_ACC
where $x[@VALID1=(11,12,19,21,22,25,26,31,45,48)]
return delete node $x

for $x in //RT_REL_ENT_ACC
where $x[@RELID1=(14,15,16,17,19)]
return delete node $x
```

How can I merge the upper 2(or more) queries into 1 final script instead of having to execute multiple in succession? It seems simple but I can't seem to wrap my head around the xquery options I can use here...

Comment: Have you tried executing both FLWOR expressions in a single query by adding a comma (`,`) between them?

Comment: I tried using a comma, it works in the For but not in the Return statement

Comment: OMG dude, now I understood what you meant... it really works... I knew it would be stupidly simple but I never reckoned it was THAT STUPIDLY simple... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: by just adding a ',' in between the queries...